# Multiple file upload is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using this function to upload multiple image(s) .
It is working fine in new codeigniter setup . But when i am using it in existing website (codeigniter) it is not working and not showing me any warning or error . I am not getting what i am missing . It is not showing me anything after calling the function $this->upload->do_multi_upload("uploadfile") .

```
  public function do_upload(){
    // Detect form submission.
    if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $path = './uni_images/';
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize(array(
            "upload_path"       =>  $path,
            "allowed_types"     =>  "gif|jpg|png",
            "max_size"          =>  '10000',
            "max_width"         =>  '1024000',
            "max_height"        =>  '7680000'
        ));
        if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("uploadfile")){
           echo "12";
            $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data();
            echo '<p class = "bg-success">' . count($data['upload_data']) . 'File(s) successfully uploaded.</p>';
        } else {   
        echo "13";
            // Output the errors
            $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors('<p class = "bg-danger">', '</p>'));              

            foreach($errors as $k => $error){
                echo $error;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p class = "bg-danger">An error occured, please try again later.</p>';
    }
    exit();
}
```

here is my html code to call above function

```
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('welcome_image/do_upload', array('class' => 'upload-image-form'));?>
        <input type="file" multiple = "multiple" accept = "image/*" class = "form-control" name="uploadfile[]" size="20" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Upload" class = "btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
```

Comment: What CI version you have in existing site ?

Comment: how can i check that ??

Comment: Or look for the define in system/core/CodeIgniter.php

Comment: As far as I know, `do_multi_upload` method is not built-in method in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set ENVIRONMENT to `development` and add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in index.php under your root directory to appear error. Moreover, make sure your `./uni_images/` path is writable.

As far as I know, `do_multi_upload` is not built-in method in upload library of codeigniter. [Here](https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload) is a third-party library by extending native codeigniter upload library.

Hope it will be useful for you.